# What is the parent process when we do a fork() system call?

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

I am taking an operating systems course.
I am currently studying the chapter on process management.

Let's say I write code as such:

```
void main(){
    int pid = fork();
    // Some code goes here
}
```

This code basically creates a child process that is a duplicate of the parent process. Everything is the same between the processes except for the PID. What is the parent process exactly? Is it the C program(running the a.out file) in execution?

Comment: The parent process is the process in which `fork` returned a value greater than zero.  Or, the parent process is the process in which `getpid` and `getppid` return the same values that it would have before the `fork`.  Or, it is the process that can use `wait` to recover the exit status of the child.  To first order there are no other differences between the parent and the child.  If you're really asking the question "what is a process?" then please clarify.

Comment: No I know what a process is. What is confusing me is: is the process, the C program itself in execution the parent process? And then when I do fork() now there are two process dealing with this code in execution

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot make any sense out of "is the process, the C program itself in execution the parent process?".  Every process has exactly one program that it is executing (unless it's a zombie), but the process and the program are two separate and incomparable things.  (And, since I suspect this is key to your confusion, *any number* of processes can be executing the *same* program at the same time.)

Comment: (It is less wrong, though still inaccurate in certain key respects, to identify "the program" with "the a.out file.")

Answer (score 0):

When execution starts, there is one process. After fork() there are two processes that will execute the code at 'Some code goes here'. So it actually clones the process as it is executing the call to fork(), and that cloned process gets a new pid.

The original process is called the parent process.

Comment: When fork() is done, the parent process will stop execution while the child process is running?

Comment: No, they will both run at the same time, for instance on two processors.

Answer (score 0):

parent process is the process who give birth to other process- child process. in main() of example.c you use fork(): to generate identical process. what does identical in context of your confusion is that both executes instructions from example.c unless a specific event occurs which detach the child process from example.c. in part of child process code (pid< 0) you can use exec family functions to detach child from example.c.

So parent and child both use same program for their execution segregated by return value of fork. the difference between before and after fork is that now you have place parent and child code in their specific places